# Fetch the latest image from ACR that doesn't start with a prefix

Tags: bash, azure, azure-cli, acr

I'm gonna fetch the latest image from ACR repository which doesn't include a specific prefix:
Here is what I have now:

```
$ az acr repository show-tags --name myacr --repository myrepo --orderby time_desc --top 1 --output tsv
```

The list of images are like this:

```
"prefix-7471",
"prefix-7470",
"7469",
"prefix-7467",
"prefix-7466",
"prefix-7459",
"7455",
...
```

The above command shows the tag : "prefix-7471" as output however I want it to fetch tag: "7469"

Is there anyway that I can get this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about using grep?

```
az acr repository show-tags --name myacr --repository myrepo --orderby time_desc \
    --output tsv | grep -v "prefix"
```

and then you can take the first string from the output

ps. I dont think you can do `notcontains` jmespath query?

Comment: Almost but that command shows me all the tags except the ones with prefix, then how can I get the latest/toppest one among them?

Comment: its sorted by time, so the first line should be the one you are looking at

Comment: add `| head -1` to the end